# Would this be the best way to do this?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn JavaScript by writing a Google Chrome extension for Reddit so I wrote something to display both link and comment karma in the little tab up top.

```
a = document.getElementById("header-bottom-right");
a.firstChild.firstChild.nextElementSibling.innerText = "100000"
```

Obviously it is not the full thing (just finding the correct nodes to edit), but is their a better way to grab the karma text?

Comment: Can you post the relevant markup too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reddit uses jQuery library (an ancient version, but still). So instead of using plain js you could use: `$('#header-bottom-right child_tag').html('10000')` (you can also use custom html there)

With plain js could be something like this:

```
var hbr = document.getElementById('header-bottom-right');
var links = hbr.getElementsByTagName('a'); // replace this with what tag you want to change
links[0].innerHTML = 'your cool text';
```

Comment: i added a js solution as well.

Comment: Thanks, getting by tags will future proof this!

Answer (score 0):

May not be the *best* way, but you may be able to use `innerHTML` instead.

```
document.getElementById('header-bottom-right').firstChild.firstChild.nextElementSibling.innerHTML
```